# PNG image appears in IE8, disappears in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, png

I'm attempting to display a logo (PNG created in Paint.NET) on my web page (XHTML 1.0 Transitional), like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" />
    </div>
  <!-- etc. -->
```

`.header` is styled as follows:

```
.header {
  background-color: Black;
  color: White;
  margin-left: -3em;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.header .logo {
  float: right;
}
```

The logo is white-on-black, with some other colours.

On IE8 (and Google Chrome), the image is displayed correctly. On IE7, the image is not displayed at all. What am I doing wrong?

I don't care about IE6.

Comment: `I don't care about IE6` ...  I'm jealous

Comment: Might want to add HTML and CSS in your tags.

Comment: It appears to be the `float: right` that messes it up; if I remove that, then the image appears. Alternatively, if I remove the `background-color`, then the image appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the float:right that messes it up perheps you should try to clear your floats. Try setting overflow:hidden; on .header class, or apply clear:both on the element that follows it in the markup.

Also the img tag always requires the alt attribute - you can however leave it blank - alt=""

Comment: By setting th attribute overflow:hidden; on the container div you somehow remid it that it is wrapping the element inside it and it somehow clear itself. I believe it is considered as a CSS bug but works in all browsers. You can also clear it with :auto or :scroll properties and sometimes you will need to set width too (100% usually does it). 
Just watch out, to not use this to clear a div containing dropdown menus, or with ay other situations where content is offset out of the container, since it will cut it at the edge.

Answer (score 1):

If you drag-drop the image directly into IE7 does it display correctly?

If it does, then the issue isn't with the image but it's with your HTML or the CSS.

I don't have IE7 here so can't test directly, but I can recommend a simple approach to troubleshooting:

- Remove the CSS styles one-by-one until the image renders in all of your target browsers. That should tell you *what* is causing the issue (hopefully the reason *why* will then be relatively easy to fathom)

Answer (score 0):

HTML or XHTML? Don't think that a self-closing img-tag is valid in HTML.

EDIT: You are also missing the alt-attribute.

Comment: It's a logo; it has no vision-impaired equivalent. Do I still need an alt-attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem in an MVC.NET application using an IMG tag with a src=data string.

At the end of the day, I don't care what's causing it, since it's 1 image out of 60000 (and only in IE)

```
function showPicture() {
        if ($('#picture').css("display") == "none") {
            $('#picture').css("display", "");
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))
        interval = setInterval(showPicture, 500);
```

While I think it's strange that only certain records cause the Display:None attribute to be applied inline, I'm comfortable with sharing this, since the CSS Display:None is not coming from my code.

At any rate, theoretically, you can check to see if it's IE before running this code using the snippet from [check for IE browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/jquery-check-if-user-is-using-ie)