# Check if user is using IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser-detection

I am calling a function like the one below by click on divs with a certain class.

Is there a way I can check when starting the function if a user is using Internet Explorer and abort / cancel it if they are using other browsers so that it only runs for IE users ? The users here would all be on IE8 or higher versions so I would not need to cover IE7 and lower versions.

If I could tell which browser they are using that would be great but is not required.

**Example function:**

```
$('.myClass').on('click', function(event)
{
    // my function
});
```

Comment: Here are a lot of examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript

Comment: Use modernizer to detect IE or other browsers.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478303/correct-way-to-use-modernizr-to-detect-ie

Comment: Please note, with modern web development, it's bad practice to detect browsers.

Comment: By modern web development standards, it's bad practice to develop for old versions of IE to begin with.

Comment: Actually, this "bad practice" is forced by the standards themselves, so it's not the developer's fault... Browsers work differently and and the specs are too soft on implementation issues. In order to make something that is not buggy and not boring as hell one *has* to do browser detection. I would suggest an other best practice: `With modern web development, it's bad practice to support non-Chromium-based browsers (with Safari not considered to be Chromium-based at all)`. Sorry, but this insanity must end at some point and somehow...

Comment: It is better practice today to do "feature detection" over "browser detection".  Ask whether the browser does what you need instead.

Comment: @ChrisRogers - That sounds great and all, but if you need to add some inline styles because of a [bug in how IE measures the size of child elements of a flexbox element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35073868/211627), then yeah... you need browser detection.

Comment: @JDB - Well.. erm.. yeah, of course. I don't think anyone's laying down absolute laws here. I still stand by the advice of what is *preferable*. What's more, the example given by the OP does not necessarily imply they are about to write a CSS hack.  On the surface, it's appears reasonably likely that they are about to call some javascript function.

Comment: @Chris - apologies... meant for that to have more of a jokey tone. I'm going to blame IE for stealing my joy and leaving me with bitterness and frustration. :)

Comment: @JDB - no worries at all.  IE (aka. "the moon faced assassin of joy") has extinguished many a soul. :-)

Comment: Build something cool! Does it work? No?! Here you go, it's an IE.

Comment: @Rosseyn By modern development standards, it's bad practice to use an application as bad as IE to begin with. Nevertheless, the pandemic that is IE is forever. As long as customers are too naive to use something else, our jobs depend on satisfying them despite the carnage that follows.

Comment: Can "with jQuery" be removed from the question title so it just says "Check if user is using IE"? The best answers in this thread don't require any jQuery and this is the first result in Google if you type "check if IE". Having jQuery in the title might drive some people away from the question.

Comment: Forgot that I have edit permissions 

Answer (score 529, accepted):

Use below JavaScript method :

```
function msieversion() 
{
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0) // If Internet Explorer, return version number
    {
        alert(parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))));
    }
    else  // If another browser, return 0
    {
        alert('otherbrowser');
    }

    return false;
}
```

You may find the details on below Microsoft support site :

[How to determine browser version from script](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/167820)

**Update :** (IE 11 support)

```
function msieversion() {

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))  // If Internet Explorer, return version number
    {
        alert(parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))));
    }
    else  // If another browser, return 0
    {
        alert('otherbrowser');
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: although this would work well as the ua variable will never start with MSIE, writing `if (msie > 0)` is misleading. If the value is not found, the indexOf() function returns -1 not 0. Hence `if (msie > -1)` would be more explanatory.

Comment: This returns NaN in IE11, for me.

Comment: @verism and others: check this answer that also works for `IE 11`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21712356/114029

Comment: navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident") > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > 0

Comment: `/Edge\/|Trident\/|MSIE /.test(window.navigator.userAgent)` I know this works on 10 and 11.  If you can verify <IE9 and Edge, edit answer.

Comment: Nice script, although I would urge anyone to use brackets in if-else structures.

Comment: @PieterDeBie: I would consider this and edit it. thanks :)

Comment: @BenHutchison What about IE8?  I know it's *really* old at the point, but that's what the original poster wanted.

Comment: @Indolering Good point. I just tested on IE 8 and it works as well.

Comment: it gives me 8 but I have IE11.0.9600

Comment: In your update, why do you use two logical not signs (!!) ? Could they not be removed ?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane the tilde operator could actually be used here, as in `if(~msie)`

Comment: Down-voting not because this is a "bad" answer but there's a better answer from @Mario which I think is more concise. So I'd liked to have that answer actually on top.

Comment: @IvoMori: That is not the reason to down vote I guess. Instead you should upvote Mario's answer. :)

Comment: @verism, you are right. When the var msie === -1 but the Trident check is true, then it tries to substring from (-1 + 5 to the first '.'). The return is from the string 'Mozilla/5.0' which is the beginning of the userAgent string for Trident. Then parseInt('lla/5') returns NAN. I'll post an alternative below to fix this issue.

Comment: not working. It shows "mozilla 5" for me. Using IE 11.

Answer (score 726):

It's several years later, and the **Edge browser now uses Chromium as its rendering engine.**
Checking for IE 11 is still a thing, sadly.

Here is a more straightforward approach, as ancient versions of IE should be gone.

```js
if (window.document.documentMode) {
  // Do IE stuff
}
```

---

*Here is my old answer (2014):*

In Edge the *User Agent String* has changed.

```js
/**
 * detect IEEdge
 * returns version of IE/Edge or false, if browser is not a Microsoft browser
 */
function detectIEEdge() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0) {
        // IE 10 or older => return version number
        return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
    }

    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    if (trident > 0) {
        // IE 11 => return version number
        var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
        return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
    }

    var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
    if (edge > 0) {
       // Edge => return version number
       return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
    }

    // other browser
    return false;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
alert('IEEdge ' + detectIEEdge());
```

Default string of IE 10:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)
```

Default string of IE 11:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Default string of Edge 12:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0
```

Default string of Edge 13 (thx @DrCord):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
```

Default string of Edge 14:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14300
```

Default string of Edge 15:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063
```

Default string of Edge 16:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299
```

Default string of Edge 17:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134
```

Default string of Edge 18 (Insider preview):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; ServiceUI 14) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17730
```

Test at CodePen:

http://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/vEJNZN

Comment: tested in IE 9 and it doesn't work as written. The problem is that "Trident" is now in the IE9 ua string and is formatted like this: ""Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)" so the parsing failed and NaN was returned.

One fix is to make "if(trident" into "else if(trident". I've tested that on IE9 and IE11. I've taken your code & my changes and merged them into the answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16657946/684852 also.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I have not verified your answer yet, but I want to comment one thing: As the first 'if' contains a 'return', you don't need an 'else' afterwards.

Comment: But it gives the message "IE restricted this webpage from running scripts or Active X Controls". So i will have to get the users permission before doing anything?

Comment: It will not work until the user allows the page to run scripts. Yes.

Comment: Just curious, why the heck do they change the user agent line in new versions of IE? MS seriously don't want us to detect their awful web browser.

Comment: @c00000fd Because they are building their new browser implementing web standards, detecting browser is a bad practice which should be abandoned.  You should detect features instead.

Comment: @SameerAlibhai Which sounds good in theory but in practice, especially currently, it's not practical. Sometimes issues arise that a single "feature" detection doesn't encompass and plus certain features have implementation quirks that can only be worked around with knowledge of the browser. What if I want to do something simple like collect browser statistics?

Comment: It should be noted that Edge isn't really 'IE12' but is in fact a completely separate browser. Windows 10 comes with both IE11 and Edge installed.

Comment: Just a note: Edge on Windows 10 after an upgrade now reports this UA string `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586` NOTE the 13 instead of 12 as the Edge version number!

Comment: @snowYetis - they did get rid of IE, the new browser is now Edge and is much better.

Comment: Thank you @DrCord, this will show IE 13 as result. It is covered by the current script. I updated the pen (CodePen) with a new test value.

Comment: @DrCord Edge is cool. I had to fix some controls at my job so they would render properly in Edge. It does not play well with Transform:Matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Accepted answer returned NaN in IE 11 but your solution worked.

Comment: @Mario: Thank you very much that you cared enough to create a test for your solution! That's very helpful for quick verification.

Comment: Edge is NOT Internet Explorer or IE12. Please stop implying this. Also, what is the point of detecting Edge? It's Chromium based, so you should also add Opera and Chrome to this code.

Comment: @hda yes EDGE is Chromium based, so support all Chromium features? Just for this maybe want detect it.

Comment: Where did this mis-information that Edge is Chromium based come from? That is so wrong and so bizzare. Edge is a largely revamped and legacy free port of IE. Funny thing is that soon the nonsense about Chromium will be true... maybe that was why they decided to go that route - everyone thought it was a Chromium browser anyway so they just  decided "screw it, if you can't beat 'em join 'em".

Comment: @ChrisM Have you been under a rock the last couple months? Stop spreading old information
https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/

"Back in December, we announced our intention to adopt the Chromium open source project in the development of Microsoft Edge on the desktop to create better web compatibility for our customers, and less fragmentation of the web for all web developers. Now "

Comment: @Blanen ....Thus my comment about Edge becoming a Chromium based browser. But Edge-Chromium is not yet released. The current version of Edge is still based on EdgeHTML which was based on Trident. A fork that MS made in 2015 and continues to maintain to this day. Thus when people imply that checking for Edge is the same as checking for Chrome it's simply untrue. So there's no need to be insulting - you just failed to read my comment properly.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't be surprised that people are confused, but to be clear I have encountered this confusion several times before, and long before the announcement about Chromium was made. I assumed that this thread was the same mis-information, but in any case it's simply incorrect.

Comment: @ChrisM True, sorry.

Comment: @Blanen No worries. Happens sometimes :)

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Comment: This code works in IE ONLY if you place the actual function call in the main js file, not if you export it with webpack in a js module.

Comment: @MattiaRasulo thx for commenting. I updated my outdated answer and reduced it to a one-liner. :-)

Comment: This is the simplest and by far the best solution. Used it to redirect IE users to a page that suggests they rather use Edge.  I did not use it for Edge though since I find Edge even better than the clunky Chrome.  For some reason Chrome shakes when javascript curtains or carousel photo viewers render but not Edge.

Comment: Incredible IE: `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(document, 'documentMode')` returns false, but `document.documentMode === 11` is true, beware

Answer (score 166):

If all you want to know is if the browser is IE or not, you can do this:

```
var isIE = false;
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var old_ie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
var new_ie = ua.indexOf('Trident/');

if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1)) {
    isIE = true;
}

if ( isIE ) {
    //IE specific code goes here
}
```

### Update 1: A better method

I recommend this now. It is still very readable and is far less code :)

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var isIE = /MSIE|Trident/.test(ua);

if ( isIE ) {
  //IE specific code goes here
}
```

Thanks to JohnnyFun in the comments for the shortened answer :)

### Update 2: Testing for IE in CSS

Firstly, if you can, you should use `@supports` statements instead of JS for checking if a browser supports a certain CSS feature.

```css
.element {
  /* styles for all browsers */
}

@supports (display: grid) {
  .element {
    /* styles for browsers that support display: grid */
  }
}
```

(Note that IE doesn't support `@supports` at all and will ignore any styles placed inside an `@supports` statement.)

If the issue can't be resolved with `@supports` then you can do this:

```js
// JS

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var isIE = /MSIE|Trident/.test(ua);

if ( isIE ) {
  document.documentElement.classList.add('ie')
}
```

```css
/* CSS */

.element {
  /* styles that apply everywhere */
}

.ie .element {
  /* styles that only apply in IE */
}
```

(Note: `classList` is relatively new to JS and I think, out of the IE browsers, it only works in IE11. Possibly also IE10.)

If you are using SCSS (Sass) in your project, this can be simplified to:

```
/* SCSS (Sass) */

.element {
  /* styles that apply everywhere */

  .ie & {
    /* styles that only apply in IE */
  }
}
```

### Update 3: Adding Microsoft Edge (not recommended)

If you also want to add Microsoft Edge into the list, you can do the following. However **I do not recommend it** as Edge is a much more competent browser than IE.

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var isIE = /MSIE|Trident|Edge\//.test(ua);

if ( isIE ) {
  //IE & Edge specific code goes here
}
```

Comment: Or the same in a few bytes:
ms_ie = ~ua.indexOf('MSIE ') || ~ua.indexOf('Trident/');
;-)

Comment: My version makes much more immediate sense though to a human but less bytes is always good :)

Comment: or `ms_ie = !!ua.match(/MSIE|Trident/)`

Comment: or ms_ie = /MSIE|Trident/.test(ua)

Comment: @SimonSteinberger does the `~` have any significance?

Comment: Thanks.. Here's a further simplified one-liner to check: if(/MSIE|Trident/.test(window.navigator.userAgent))

Comment: @iPzard getting rid of the `ua` variable is fine. You don't want to get rid of the `isIE` variable though. Using an `isIE` variable means that you can easily test for IE again multiple times throughout your code without spending extra computation cycles computing the value again. It's also less repetitious.

Comment: I mean, how many times do you need to check if they're on IE? It's not like they can change browsers during the same page view. 

Imo, if you're checking something that's not changeable during the session (like the user's browser) more than once, the code should probably be refactored to avoid that. Just my opinion.

Comment: One component needs to check for IE. `import isIE from './isIE.js'`. Now another component for whatever reason needs to check for IE, `import isIE from './isIE.js'`. And if that isn't enough to convince you, it is simply better for readability. There are 2 reasons to use a variable: reduce code repetition; and clarify what a piece of code does. When you read `if (/MSIE|Trident/.test(window.navigator.userAgent))` it is far less immediately obvious what it is checking for when compared to `if (isIE)`

Comment: Agree 100% about Edges competency.  Edge is as good as dare I say it.  Excel.

Comment: so simple for an IE check. just what i need. thanks!

Answer (score 49):

This returns `true` for any version of Internet Explorer:

```
function isIE(userAgent) {
  userAgent = userAgent || navigator.userAgent;
  return userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1 || userAgent.indexOf("Edge/") > -1;
}
```

The `userAgent` parameter is optional and it defaults to the browser's user agent.

Comment: This should be good but you just basically forgot to set  a default "return true" or "return 1" value for IE browsers. This currently doesn't return any value when IE browsers are detected.

Comment: Why would you want to treat Edge as IE? In terms of compatibility, they have little in common nowadays.

Comment: @docta_faustus userAgent is a parameter, not a global

Answer (score 34):

You can use the navigator object to detect user-navigator, you don't need jquery for it, the 4 comments below are already included so this snippet works as expected

```
if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent) || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1 ){ 
 // Do stuff with Internet-Exploders ... :)
}
```

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml

Comment: This gives me false for my IE11

Comment: IE11's user agent is different than MSIE (X.X);

IE11's would be found by checking for Trident.

Comment: This gives a false positive in Firefox 45.0.2.

Comment: wrong test indexOf dont return true or false like test function regex
you have do   navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") != -1

Answer (score 32):

This is how the Angularjs team is doing it ([v 1.6.5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7300a5311c74a377db64db580e2e4ad3aa63570e/src/Angular.js#L191)):

```
var msie, // holds major version number for IE, or NaN if UA is not IE.

// Support: IE 9-11 only
/**
 * documentMode is an IE-only property
 * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc196988(v=vs.85).aspx
 */
msie = window.document.documentMode;
```

Then there are several lines of code scattered throughout using it as a number such as

```
if (event === 'input' && msie <= 11) return false;
```

and

```
if (enabled && msie < 8) {
```

Comment: window.document.documentMode is undefined in MS Edge

Comment: it's undefined in MS Edge because MS Edge is not IE!

Comment: `document.documentMode` is supported by IE8+. It will be `'undefined'` for Edge or Chrome/FireFox... . I changed this code to `var IEver = window.document.documentMode || (window.attachEvent? 1 : 99);` such that it returns exact IE version for IE8+, 99 for non-IE browsers (usually it will be a modern browser), and 1 for old IE5-7. This is written such because we usually need special work only for some older IE's. So, `if (IEver < 9) { ... }` means if it is an old IE

Answer (score 19):

***You can simply do this:***

```
var isIE = window.document.documentMode ? true : false; // this variable will hold if the current browser is IE
```

I know the question is old but if someone scrolled that far they can see the simple answer :)

Answer (score 11):

**Method 01:**
$.browser was deprecated in jQuery version 1.3 and removed in 1.9

```
if ( $.browser.msie) {
  alert( "Hello! This is IE." );
}
```

**Method 02:**
Using Conditional Comments

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<p>You're using a recent version of Internet Explorer.</p>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<p>Hm. You should upgrade your copy of Internet Explorer.</p>
<![endif]-->

<![if !IE]>
<p>You're not using Internet Explorer.</p>
<![endif]>
```

**Method 03:**

```
 /**
 * Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
 * (indicating the use of another browser).
 */
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
{
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.

    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
    }

    return rv;
}

function checkVersion()
{
    var msg = "You're not using Internet Explorer.";
    var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();

    if ( ver > -1 )
    {
        if ( ver >= 8.0 ) 
            msg = "You're using a recent copy of Internet Explorer."
        else
            msg = "You should upgrade your copy of Internet Explorer.";
    }

    alert( msg );
}
```

**Method 04:**
 
Use JavaScript/Manual Detection

```
/*
     Internet Explorer sniffer code to add class to body tag for IE version.
     Can be removed if your using something like Modernizr.
 */
 var ie = (function ()
 {

     var undef,
     v = 3,
         div = document.createElement('div'),
         all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

     while (
     div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i>< ![endif]-->',
     all[0]);

     //append class to body for use with browser support
     if (v > 4)
     {
         $('body').addClass('ie' + v);
     }

 }());
```

**[Reference Link](http://www.sitepoint.com/fix-jquery-browser-function/)**

Comment: @radhe I have updated the answer hopefully this will work for you.

Comment: As a note: **Method 2** will not work in IE10 or better in standard mode. For more information: [Conditional comments are no longer supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @insertusernamehere you are very right, for that i think use of `.ie10` class is one of the best options if you are doing some css fix for ie10 only. As internet explorer 10 adds `".ie10"` class to HTML element `<html class="ie10">`, you can then use it like `.ie10 .myclass {//some css here}`

Answer (score 11):

Using the answers above; simple & condensed returning Boolean:

`var isIE = /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);`

Comment: Returns false in FireFox 44.0.2 on Widnows 10. What version of FireFox returns true @SiKni8?

Answer (score 9):

I just wanted to check if the browser was IE11 or older, because well, they're crap.

```
function isCrappyIE() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var crappyIE = false;
    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0) {// IE 10 or older => return version number        
        crappyIE = true;
    }
    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    if (trident > 0) {// IE 11 => return version number        
        crappyIE = true;
    }
    return crappyIE;
}   

if(!isCrappyIE()){console.table('not a crappy browser);}
```

Comment: this gets my vote for its high regard for naming convention standards

Answer (score 8):

```
function detectIE() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var ie = ua.search(/(MSIE|Trident|Edge)/);

    return ie > -1;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Edge is not IE.

Comment: hda, question dates from 2013, I think that today, it is interesting not to ignore "Edge"

Answer (score 6):

**Using modernizr**

```
Modernizr.addTest('ie', function () {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ') > 0;
    var ie11 = ua.indexOf('Trident/') > 0;
    var ie12 = ua.indexOf('Edge/') > 0;
    return msie || ie11 || ie12;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as Edge is not IE. Also Edge is not IE12. When Chromium-based Edge is released, you should also add Chrome or Opera to this list. (Whatever you want to achieve by this, it would be easier to detect Firefox then)

Answer (score 6):

Or this really short version, returns true if the browsers is Internet Explorer:

```
function isIe() {
    return window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0
        || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this if you are using **jquery version >=1.9**,

```
var browser;
jQuery.uaMatch = function (ua) {
    ua = ua.toLowerCase();

    var match = /(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) ||
        /(webkit)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) ||
        /(opera)(?:.*version|)[ \/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) ||
        /(msie) ([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) || 
        ua.indexOf("compatible") < 0 && /(mozilla)(?:.*? rv:([\w.]+)|)/.exec(ua) ||
       /(Trident)[\/]([\w.]+)/.exec(ua) || [];

    return {
        browser: match[1] || "",
        version: match[2] || "0"
    };
};
// Don't clobber any existing jQuery.browser in case it's different
if (!jQuery.browser) {
    matched = jQuery.uaMatch(navigator.userAgent);
    browser = {};

    if (matched.browser) {
        browser[matched.browser] = true;
        browser.version = matched.version;
    }

    // Chrome is Webkit, but Webkit is also Safari.
    if (browser.chrome) {
        browser.webkit = true;
    } else if (browser.webkit) {
        browser.safari = true;
    }

    jQuery.browser = browser;
}
```

If using **jQuery version <1.9** ($.browser was removed in jQuery 1.9) use the following code instead:

```
$('.myClass').on('click', function (event) {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        alert($.browser.version);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately we are still on version 1.7.2 and cant change this yet.

Comment: As far as I can see, this does not take newer IEs into account, that are based on the Trident engine.

Comment: Updated for latest IEs based on Trident

Answer (score 5):

Yet another simple (yet human readable) function to detect if the browser is IE or not (ignoring Edge, which isn't bad at all):

```
function isIE() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE '); // IE 10 or older
  var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/'); //IE 11

  return (msie > 0 || trident > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use the useragent, you could also just do this for checking if the browser is IE.  The commented code actually runs in IE browsers and turns the "false" to "true".

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
if(isIE){
    //The browser is IE.
}else{
    //The browser is NOT IE.
}
```

Comment: IE11 doesn't support conditional compilation

Comment: I just tried this and it still worked.  Are you sure it doesn't support it?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone comes across it again and has issues with detecting IE11, here is a working solution for all current versions of IE.

```
var isIE = false;
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
    isIE = true;   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i've used this

```
function notIE(){
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    if (ua.indexOf('Edge/') > 0 || 
        ua.indexOf('Trident/') > 0 || 
        ua.indexOf('MSIE ') > 0){
       return false;
    }else{
        return true;                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Necromancing.

In order to not depend on the user-agent string, just check for a few properties:

```
if (document.documentMode) 
{
    console.log('Hello Microsoft IE User!');
}

if (!document.documentMode && window.msWriteProfilerMark) {
    console.log('Hello Microsoft Edge User!');
}

if (document.documentMode || window.msWriteProfilerMark) 
{
    console.log('Hello Microsoft User!');
}

if (window.msWriteProfilerMark) 
{
    console.log('Hello Microsoft User in fewer characters!');
}
```

Also, this detects the new Chredge/Edgium (Anaheim):

```
function isEdg()
{ 

    for (var i = 0, u="Microsoft", l =u.length; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++)
    {
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name != null && navigator.plugins[i].name.substr(0, l) === u)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And this detects chromium:

```
function isChromium()
{ 

    for (var i = 0, u="Chromium", l =u.length; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++)
    {
        if (navigator.plugins[i].name != null && navigator.plugins[i].name.substr(0, l) === u)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

And this Safari:

```
if(window.safari)
{
    console.log("Safari, yeah!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@SpiderCode's solution does not work with IE 11. Here is the best solution that I used henceforth in my code where I need browser detection for particular feature.

IE11 no longer reports as MSIE, according to this list of changes, it's intentional to avoid mis-detection.

What you can do if you really want to know it's IE is to detect the Trident/ string in the user agent if navigator.appName returns Netscape, something like (the untested);

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11/17907562#17907562)

```
function isIE()
{
  var rv = -1;
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  else if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv == -1 ? false: true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Many answers here, and I'd like to add my input. IE 11 was being such an ass concerning flexbox (see all its issues and inconsistencies [here](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs)) that I really needed an easy way to check if a user is using any IE browser (up to and including 11) but excluding Edge, because Edge is actually pretty nice.

Based on the answers given here, I wrote a simple function returning a global boolean variable which you can then use down the line. It's very easy to check for IE.

```
var isIE;
(function() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent,
        msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE '),
        trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');

    isIE = (msie > -1 || trident > -1) ? true : false;
})();

if (isIE) {
    alert("I am an Internet Explorer!");
}
```

This way you only have to do the look up once, and you store the result in a variable, rather than having to fetch the result on each function call. (As far as I know you don't even have to wait for document ready to execute this code as the user-agent is not related to the DOM.)

Answer (score 1):

Below I found elegant way of doing this while googling ---

```
/ detect IE
var IEversion = detectIE();

if (IEversion !== false) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'IE ' + IEversion;
} else {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'NOT IE';
}

// add details to debug result
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = window.navigator.userAgent;

/**
 * detect IE
 * returns version of IE or false, if browser is not Internet Explorer
 */
function detectIE() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

  // Test values; Uncomment to check result …

  // IE 10
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)';

  // IE 11
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';

  // IE 12 / Spartan
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0';

  // Edge (IE 12+)
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586';

  var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
  if (msie > 0) {
    // IE 10 or older => return version number
    return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
  }

  var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
  if (trident > 0) {
    // IE 11 => return version number
    var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
    return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
  }

  var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
  if (edge > 0) {
    // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
    return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
  }

  // other browser
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the code from [my pen at CodePen](http://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/vEJNZN), that is part of [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie-with-jquery#answer-21712356). ;-)

Comment: Yes I used the same but stack-overflow people don't wants to share link. will update link in reference here onwards.   Thanks for the great work Mario.

Answer (score 1):

Update to SpiderCode's answer to fix issues where the string 'MSIE' returns -1 but it matches 'Trident'. It used to return NAN, but now returns 11 for that version of IE.

```
   function msieversion() {
       var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
       var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
       if (msie > -1) {
           return ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie));
       } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
           return 11;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I landed on this page in 2020, and I see that till IE5 all userAgent string have `Trident`, I'm not sure if they have changed anything. So checking only for Trident in the userAgent worked for me.

```
var isIE = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident') > -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to detect IE without trying to look at the User-Agent:

```js
var usingIE="__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_EVAL_ERROR" in document;
alert("You are"+(usingIE?"":"n't")+" using Internet Explorer.");
```

I happened to find this by accident when I was testing if my site worked on IE, and I went to the debugger and clicked the folder icon.  It has my scripts, and also a `Dynamic Scripts` folder that I didn't have.  I opened it and found lots of `browsertools.library.js` files.  Inside them I found stuff like:

```js
document.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_EVAL_RESULT = undefined;
document.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_EVAL_ERROR = false;
document.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_EVAL_ERRORCODE = undefined;
try{
document.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_EVAL_RESULT = eval("\r\n//# sourceURL=browsertools://browsertools.library.js");
}
catch( eObj ){
document.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_EVAL_ERRORCODE = eObj.number;
document.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_EVAL_RESULT = eObj.message || eObj.description || eObj.toString();
document.__IE_DEVTOOLBAR_CONSOLE_EVAL_ERROR = true;
}
```

So I used these to test if the user's browser was IE.  Just note this only works if you want to know if they have IE, not exactly what version of IE they have.

Answer (score 0):

You can dectect all Internet Explorer (Last Version Tested 12).

```
<script>
    var $userAgent = '';
    if(/MSIE/i['test'](navigator['userAgent'])==true||/rv/i['test'](navigator['userAgent'])==true||/Edge/i['test'](navigator['userAgent'])==true){
       $userAgent='ie';
    } else {
       $userAgent='other';
    }

    alert($userAgent);
</script>
```

See here https://jsfiddle.net/v7npeLwe/

Answer (score 0):

```
function msieversion() {
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
console.log(ua);
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

if (msie > -1 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv:11\./)) { 
    // If Internet Explorer, return version numbe
    // You can do what you want only in IE in here.
    var version_number=parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie)));
    if (isNaN(version_number)) {
        var rv_index=ua.indexOf("rv:");
        version_number=parseInt(ua.substring(rv_index+3,ua.indexOf(".",rv_index)));
    }
    console.log(version_number);
} else {       
    //other browser   
    console.log('otherbrowser');
}
}
```

You should see the result in console, please use chrome Inspect.

Answer (score 0):

I've placed this code in the document ready function and it only triggers in internet explorer. Tested in Internet Explorer 11.

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
ms_ie = /MSIE|Trident/.test(ua);
if ( ms_ie ) {
    //Do internet explorer exclusive behaviour here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This only work below IE 11 version.

```
var ie_version = parseInt(window.navigator.userAgent.substring(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") + 5, window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf(".", window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE "))));
```

`console.log("version number",ie_version);`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript function to detect the version of Internet Explorer or Edge

```
function ieVersion(uaString) {
  uaString = uaString || navigator.userAgent;
  var match = /\b(MSIE |Trident.*?rv:|Edge\/)(\d+)/.exec(uaString);
  if (match) return parseInt(match[2])
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing like this

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8) {
    //my stuff

}
```

Comment: jQuery deprecated this in 1.3 and completely removed in 1.9.

Answer (score -1):

I think it will help you [Here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo)

```
function checkIsIE() {
    var isIE = false;
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0) {
        isIE = true;
    }
    if (isIE)  // If Internet Explorer, return version number
    {
        kendo.ui.Window.fn._keydown = function (originalFn) {
            var KEY_ESC = 27;
            return function (e) {
                if (e.which !== KEY_ESC) {
                    originalFn.call(this, e);
                }
            };
        }(kendo.ui.Window.fn._keydown);

        var windowBrowser = $("#windowBrowser").kendoWindow({
            modal: true,
            id: 'dialogBrowser',
            visible: false,
            width: "40%",
            title: "Thông báo",
            scrollable: false,
            resizable: false,
            deactivate: false,
            position: {
                top: 100,
                left: '30%'
            }
        }).data('kendoWindow');
        var html = '<br /><div style="width:100%;text-align:center"><p style="color:red;font-weight:bold">Please use the browser below to use the tool</p>';
        html += '<img src="/Scripts/IPTVClearFeePackage_Box/Images/firefox.png"/>';
        html += ' <img src="/Scripts/IPTVClearFeePackage_Box/Images/chrome.png" />';
        html += ' <img src="/Scripts/IPTVClearFeePackage_Box/Images/opera.png" />';
        html += '<hr /><form><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Đóng trình duyệt" onclick="window.close()"></form><div>';
        windowBrowser.content(html);
        windowBrowser.open();

        $("#windowBrowser").parent().find(".k-window-titlebar").remove();
    }
    else  // If another browser, return 0
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `$.browser` to get name, vendor and version information.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: "This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin."