# How to prevent resource from being loaded if ie10 and below?

Tags: javascript, polymer

a bit of a specific question. I've been reading about how to target ie10 and below but really haven't found any concrete answer that works for my situation.

I'm using a framework for my website that does not support ie10 (google's polymer) very well so I have an alternate page set up for when the user is using ie10 and below. I'm running into the issue that when I open my webpage in ie10, the resource required to get polymer to run `platform.js` is causing so many errors that it's preventing the rest of my resources from loading somehow. `platform.js` is at the top of my loading order, and I'm not loading asynchronously. I'm trying to target ie10 in a js file that has to load underneath `platform.js` but my code isn't registering at all due to `platform.js` causing so many errors.

I am wondering if there is a way to only load `platform.js` if the browser is `!ie10` while still putting it at the top of the load order. Ugh this is driving me insane. Even a link to where I can read about how to make my resources load only on certain events would be helpful. Thanks for any info!

Comment: Perhaps related: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19233

Comment: yeah I have read through that -- the updated version doesn't seem to help with the numerous errors at all. the errors are all related to using the operand 'instanceof', which ie10 seems to not understand

Comment: In which case I'd suggest using a test case to feature detect support for that operand (though I'll note that IE is supposed to understand [`instanceof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/zh0zb36z(v=vs.94).aspx), according to Microsoft, in Quirks mode and Standards mode, in IE6 and above).

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm sorry I can't be of more immediate use. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out a way to do this using [Mario's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712356/2272445), in case anyone in the future is interested:

I popped this at the start of the head in my index.html file:

```
<script>
    function detectIE() {
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
        var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');

        if (msie > 0) {
            // IE 10 or older => return version number
            return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
        }

        if (trident > 0) {
            // IE 11 (or newer) => return version number
            var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
            return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
        }

        // other browser
        return false;
    }

    // making sure it's working..
    console.log(detectIE());

    // this is important: if you just say <= 10 then it will also accept ZERO
    // and ZERO is = false, which makes good browsers like Chrome detect as IE
    if (detectIE() >= 1 && detectIE() <= 10) {
        console.log('this is below ie10');
    } else {
        // add my script for polymer
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "/bower_components/platform/platform.js";

        //put it at the start of the head tag
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    }

</script>
```

I have noticed a tiny bit of lag sometimes when the website first loads, but it's not too bad. This will have to do until I get better at using stuff like Modernizr.