# How to position a css dropdown menu in the same place IE and Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

I have a dropdown that opens when you click an icon (the little black filter thing that is in fact a link) in a grid that's inside a dialog. It is positioned perfectly in Chrome if I get the co-ordinates from target.position().

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like in Chrome using target.position():

```
scope.showFilterMenu = function ($event, id) {
   var modal = $('div[kendo-window]');
   var target = $($event.currentTarget);
   var offset = target.position(); // THIS WORKS FOR CHROME BUT NOT IE
   var offset = target.offset(); // THIS WORKS FOR IE BUT NOT CHROME
   var top = offset.top;
   var left = offset.left + 25; // 25 is extra buffer
   modal.append(filterMenu);               
   var filterMenu = $('ul[sgid=' + id + ']'); // the dropdown menu is a ul list             
   filterMenu.css({
      'width': 50 + 'px',
      'top': dd_top + 'px',
      'position': 'fixed', // must be fixed so that it follows the window contract and expand
      'left': left // align LHS with filter icon
   });
```

}

[image]

But using target.position() in IE throws it off completely and I have to use target.offset() instead. Does anyone know how I can find a solution for both browsers please?

[image]

Comment: Which IE Version are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you make a simple `if condition`? Like `if(IE) {X} else {Y}`

```
var IE = (document.all) ? true : false;
```

---

Edit:

In addition you can check this too:

```
var ie_browser = jQuery.browser.msie;
```

Ok, ignore this one. It was removed in jQuery 1.9.

---

Maybe this helps:
There is a IE 11 update included.
[Check if user is using IE with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/jquery-check-if-user-is-using-ie)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did think of that. Have to run it by my boss first :-( Is that a completely fail-safe check, (document.all)?

Comment: I don´t know if it is 100% save. Maybe you have to check it for IE11. 10 and lower should work fine. See my edit.