# Display alert in all browsers other than google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser, dreamweaver

My current web page only displays properly in google chrome. Therefore, I would like to make browsers other than google chrome display a pop up that says "please use google chrome".

Currently I am using

> alert("Please use Google Chrome");

but the problem here is that it also displays that alert in google chrome. Is there any way to display this alert in specific browsers only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
```

This checks if the browser is chrome so now what you can do:

```
if (is_chrome != true) {alert("Please use Google Chrome")}
```

or

```
if (is_chrome != true) {prompt("Please use Google Chrome Download it here:", "https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/index.html")}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response, however, I don't understand exactly where to put the first and second codes

Comment: in <script type="javascript"></script> tags?

Comment: so I stack both codes on top of each other like this?

<script>
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

if (is_chrome != true) {alert("Please use Google Chrome")}
</script>

Comment: except in IE for some reason

Comment: I wouldn't bother with IE users, if they want to be stuck with the "outdated" browsers, then let them http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp also: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: There, for IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/jquery-check-if-user-is-using-ie