# trying to implement if , if , if statement but having trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery

so basically I am trying to create a ie9 specific if statement that basically says if the menu collapsed = true move 3 classes from the left and the opposite for if it is false... can't seem to get this statement working though can someone help ? this is what i have so far ...

```
var ms_ie = false;
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var old_ie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
var new_ie = ua.indexOf('Trident/');

if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1)) {
    ms_ie = true;
}
if ( ms_ie ) {        
    if $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: false}) {
        $( ".navbtn, .submenu-ctn, .logo-title" ).animate({
            left: "+=310",
        }, 500);             
        else {
            $( ".navbtn, .submenu-ctn, .logo-title" ).animate({
                left: "-=310",
            }, 500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "can't seem to get this statement working" have you tried debugging to see where your problem is?

Comment: Check the console. this if-statement has no parentheses: `if $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: false})`. Fix your syntax errors.

Comment: Your code isn't syntactically valid. Open your JavaScript console and you'll see.

Comment: Missing `(` before `multilevelpushmenu`

Comment: @tryingmybest This doesn't answer the question, but you can sometimes make your code clearer if you use boolean logic instead of `if` statements. [Here](http://pastebin.com/nG5CPjnk) are the first couple lines of your program written in boolean logic.

Comment: yes i know this might be the case , but i am putting braces all over the place and wanted someone to guide me that actually understands javascript

Comment: can i even have an if , if, if statement ?

Comment: if, if, if statements are totes amazeballs man

Comment: FYI this is not a place for "guiding". Hire a tutor or hit a up a chatroom. Or both.

Comment: Also hehehe I haven't seen code like this since the 90s :D

Comment: @JoshWillik: `if` statements are boolean logic.

Comment: what is wrong with the code ?

Comment: I was just referring to the style, and the switching on user-agent like we had to do back in the olden days. You're following some old guides I think.  Doesn't really matter for now.

Comment: these are fixes for internet explorer 9 problems ... this is the last one ... the statement still doesn't work even with all the tips you gave , great

Comment: Well, we've told you how to fix two problems. Now take what you've learnt and use it to fix the next problem. And the next, and the next...! Step one is to fix your indentation so that it's consistent: turns out you weren't short a `}` at all. It just looked like you were.

Comment: Don't edit new problems into a question. This is a professional Q&A for concrete problems, not a chat room or message board! Spend some time trying to resolve your new problem (preferably _at least_ a few hours) then, if you're still stuck, consider posting a new question for it. But note that it's not likely to be well-received if it's just a syntax thing.

Comment: i appreciate you advice , i am new to this , i must say though i havev been working on the for 8 hrs straight and googled the hell out of it , this was a last resort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out in comments, your code is not syntactically valid. You need one additional closing tag as below.

You have not included the relevant HTML & CSS that might go along with this, so it is hard to judge precisely what effect you are going for.

```
var ms_ie = false;
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var old_ie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
var new_ie = ua.indexOf('Trident/');


if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1)) {
    ms_ie = true;
}
if ( ms_ie ) { // CT1

    if ($('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: false})) { // Parentheses around condition.
        $( ".navbtn, .submenu-ctn, .logo-title" ).animate({
            left: "+=310",
        }, 500); 

        else {
            $( ".navbtn, .submenu-ctn, .logo-title" ).animate({
                left: "-=310",
            }, 500);
        }
    } // close CT 1 - last one included in example.
} // Needs one more closing tag :)
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19999868/1511043) to the issue of detecting IE with Javascript. Might make for a cleaner and more readable version of code. You can get a numeric IE version from that function.

Comment: i just figured out the extra tag at the end but looking at the answer now thank you for visually explaining

Comment: my debug tells me that it is expecting a ( after the if  bit in the if $('menu')

Comment: Correct - just updated in my answer. As @LightnessRacesinOrbit points out, conditions within each `if` statement must be surrounded by parentheses.

Comment: yes i saw that and appreciate it , It is now saying that i need a : after the 500 , i don't think the examples of timers i saw with animate had that though

Comment: _"You need one additional closing tag as below."_ That's actually not true. His indentation is misleading.

Comment: now i am totally confused , lightness you sound like you know what you are talking about but i am going backwards here not forward

Comment: @tryingmybest: If you feel frustrated, it's time to take a break. Go have some food, take some deep breaths. Then come back, read everything that's been said (_everything!_) and think it through logically.

Comment: No not frustrated , just confused lol here is what it is saying in debug  if ($('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: false})) {
        $( ".navbtn, .submenu-ctn, .logo-title" ).animate({
            left: "+=310",
        }IDENTFIER EXPECTED HERE, 500); 

        else {

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your "if, if, if statement"; it's just one of the if statements that's wrong:

```
if $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: false}) {
```

Parentheses!!!

```
if ($('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({Collapsed: false})) {
```

When you're developing for the web, try to use your browser's development tools. They will tell you all about syntax errors.

Comment: i think i just explained the error i was getting that you just posted an answer too .. thanks ! ... ttally agee using a javascript efitor that has some debug , i am learning

Comment: @tryingmybest: Keep it up. Good luck