# detect internet explorer in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

how to detect internet explorer in jquery?

I tried using

```
let browser= navigator.useragent();
if(browser.includes("Trident")){}
```

I read jquery documentation and it recommends using modenizr.

I tried this also

`$.browser.msie;`

this does not work also.

I have a css that is not supported by internet explorer.  What is the best option to do.

Comment: **[A simple search on google would have given you the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)**

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie-with-jquery