# Browser Detection in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there any way to detect IE browser with React and either redirect to a page or give any helpful message. I found something in JavaScript, but not sure how would I use it with React+TypeScript.

`var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You are on the right track you can use these to conditionally render jsx or help with routing...

I have used the following with great success.

Originally from - [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

```
// Opera 8.0+
const isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

// Firefox 1.0+
const isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

// Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
const isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && safari.pushNotification));

// Internet Explorer 6-11
const isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

// Edge 20+
const isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

// Chrome 1 - 71
const isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);

// Blink engine detection
const isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;
```

Please be aware they each stand a chance to deprecated due to browser changes.

I use them in React like this:

```
 content(props){
    if(!isChrome){
     return (
      <Otherjsxelements/>
     )
    }
    else { 
     return (
      <Chromejsxelements/>
     )
    }
  }
```

Then by calling {this.Content()} in my main component to render the different browser specific elements.

Pseudo code might look something like this... (untested):

```
import React from 'react';

const isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);

export default class Test extends React.Component {

  content(){
    if(isChrome){
        return (
            <div>Chrome</div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div>Not Chrome</div>
        )
    }
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Content to be seen on all browsers</div>
            {this.content()}
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have this change modal content for instance, or even depending on your router have it call a function and redirect you to a help page. Please just let me know if you need an additional breakdown of where these parts each fit inside of the component.

Comment: It might be a good idea to look into a library like the one @Tallboy provided as that stands a better chance of being updated more regularly. Then just use the example I provided for the React integration.

Comment: Maybe try this... let isSafari   = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1; these methods are changed fairly often.

Comment: These are now deprecated

Comment: As mentioned, isChrome only works upto version 71. But can't use it for current version 95. This is not a solution for chrome then.

Answer (score 35):

Not sure why but nobody mentioned this package: [react-device-detect](https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect)
The package have a lot browsers checks, plus versions and some other info related.
It's really small and it's updated.

You can use:

```
import { isIE } from 'react-device-detect';
isIE // returns true or false
```

react-device-detect it's also very small [bundlephobia link](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=react-device-detect@1.13.1)

Comment: Sure, I got it now @HafizTemuri , but maybe you should try to add that info on your next question, we're devs, not clairvoyants. In my personal opinion the package save us a good time in some ways: firstly because you don't have to make any code yourself and secondly you'll not spend time refactoring that code because some browser version doesn't support your code any more. I enforce the info about the package size because, in my personal opinion, in this case a light package is not an overkill, an overkill is spend time with premature optimization. https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: I don't think it's useful to put down this post. A package is a perfectly reasonable way to approach the issue, and does have several advantages, namely that the creator/contributors may have thought of edge cases that you haven't, and that what works and doesn't with device/browser detection changes frequently; I personally would rather not have to update my code every time it does.

Comment: Although I'm a bit late to the discussion, @LucasAndrade was only trying to be helpful. No matter how good one may be in programming, there will almost always be edge cases to miss.

Comment: @LucasAndrade Seems like someone deleted my comment, but it was in my question in case you missed it, `not sure how would I use it with React+TypeScript`. Packages are good until they get bugs and you overturn everything to update a package, only to realize its filled with bugs, then you spend extra time to downgrade. My theory is, write it yourself if you can. And for such a small problem, I don't think anyone should be using a package. And of course there needs to be a balance there, don't go in other direction and try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I just used this package, accessed on Safari and it doesn't work

Answer (score 8):

This is the service I always use when doing JS/Browser based browser-detection: http://is.js.org/

```
if (is.ie() || is.edge()) {
  window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
}
```

Comment: This could end up in never ending redirect loop. This is not an ideal way of handling it in my opinion.

Comment: How would an infinite redirect happen in my case? You simply would ensure that doesn't happen on that page. How else would you redirect to a page based on browser though without creating a situation for a potential redirect loop?

Comment: You said in your original message, "redirect to a page", so I answered exactly what you asked.

Comment: Not to mention, the answer you just marked as correct is identical to my answer without the redirect, which was what you originally asked for.

Comment: redirect to a page of the same application. It could end up in the same `if` statement and making it redirect over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

I was using Gatsby for our React site and build was giving me trouble with the accepted answer, so I ended up using a `useEffect` on load to be able to not render for IE at a minimum:

```
  const [isIE, setIsIE] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`UA: ${window.navigator.userAgent}`);
    var msie = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ");
    setIsIE(msie > 0)
  }, []);

  if(isIE) {
    return <></>
  }

// In my component render

if(isIE) { return <></> }
```

Got the idea originally from:

https://medium.com/react-review/how-to-create-a-custom-usedevicedetect-react-hook-f5a1bfe64599

and

[Check if user is using IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie)

Comment: What kind of troubles? I personally don't like the use of state and `useEffect` here. You can still implement this approach with a static `const` outside the component. `const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0`. You can still keep the check in your component. `if (isIE)`

Comment: @HafizTemuri use of `document` or `documentMode` in gatsby build throws a variety of errors and it also has trouble using `window` logic on build as well.

By putting inside a hook, it doesn't run on build and allows HTML to be compiled fully, and then on run, actually define the variables.

Comment: and people use a framework like that? That would drive me nuts if I cannot use `window` object. And a lot of time we don't need to put things in `useState`. They should have a `window` available especially when they claim to generate static HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
const isEdge = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge') != -1
const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident') != -1 && !isEdge
```

etc.

Each browser has a distinct user agent you can check.

These can be faked by the client of course, but in my opinion, are a more reliable long term solution.

Comment: You can't directly use this as navigator has to run only on/after the DOM render.

Answer (score 1):

You can write test for IE like this.

```
<script>
     // Internet Explorer 6-11
          const isIE = document.documentMode;
          if (isIE){
            window.alert(
              "Your MESSAGE here."
            )
          }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This almost broke me, but I found something which seems pretty simple and straight forward, use the vendor name. ie. Google, Apple etc. `navigator.vendor.includes('Apple')`
I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Opera now uses Chromium, so the `vendor` shows up as `Google Inc.` as well.

Comment: Firefox shows an empty string, so this is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
navigator.browserDetection= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
        if(tem!= null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return M.join(' ');
})();

console.log(navigator.browserDetection); // outputs: `Chrome 92`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new package that takes care of this for React: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-browser-navigator

This is how you can use it:

```js
// import the module
import useNavigator from "react-browser-navigator";

function App() {
  // importing the property
  let { userAgent } = useNavigator();

  // you can use it within the useEffect hook OR simply print the 
  // string into the return statement
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isNull(userAgent)) {
      // printing out the entire object
      console.log("userAgent", userAgent);
    }
  }, [userAgent]);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>userAgent:</span> {userAgent}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Essentially, the output will be something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I updated the content...

Answer (score -1):

This is all information you can get from your the browser of you client (using react):

```
    let latitude
    let longitude
    const location = window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation

    if (location) {
      location.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude
        longitude = position.coords.longitude
      })
    }

    var info = {
      timeOpened: new Date(),
      timezone: new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60,
      pageon: window.location.pathname,
      referrer: document.referrer,
      previousSites: window.history.length,
      browserName: window.navigator.appName,
      browserEngine: window.navigator.product,
      browserVersion1a: window.navigator.appVersion,
      browserVersion1b: navigator.userAgent,
      browserLanguage: navigator.language,
      browserOnline: navigator.onLine,
      browserPlatform: navigator.platform,
      javaEnabled: navigator.javaEnabled(),
      dataCookiesEnabled: navigator.cookieEnabled,
      dataCookies1: document.cookie,
      dataCookies2: decodeURIComponent(document.cookie.split(';')),
      dataStorage: localStorage,
      sizeScreenW: window.screen.width,
      sizeScreenH: window.screen.height,
      sizeDocW: window.document.width,
      sizeDocH: window.document.height,
      sizeInW: window.innerWidth,
      sizeInH: window.innerHeight,
      sizeAvailW: window.screen.availWidth,
      sizeAvailH: window.screen.availHeight,
      scrColorDepth: window.screen.colorDepth,
      scrPixelDepth: window.screen.pixelDepth,
      latitude,
      longitude
    }
    console.log(info)
```

The browser is `browserName`

Comment: Even though I am using `Chrome` but it still says `Netscape` for `window.navigator.appName`

Comment: Same result for `Firefox`, `Edge` and `IE`

Comment: right.. I founded chrome in: `"browserVersion1a": "5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36"` and `"browserVersion1b": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: Thanks, I know that is informative, but I dont think this will be helpful. Since you will have to do a lot of parsing to get the name out. Plus if they decided to change the format it will stop working. I am going to stick with @Shawn Matthews's answer for now.