# How to detect chrome browser in version 83?

Tags: reactjs, browser, version

I have seen on this link [Browser Detection in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328382/browser-detection-in-reactjs) how to detect different browsers.
In the chrome it puts from version 1 to 71, I have version 83, so the variable does not detect it, is it false, does anyone have any updated version?

```
// Chrome 1 - 71
const isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
```

Thank you

Comment: I think 1-71 means it was tested on those versions, so far. Might still work on some more versions, with some luck, but might also be true for some Chrome-lookalikes. That's how I interpret the "1-71" code comment.
Your question should probably go as a comment on the page you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe navigator.vendor.includes('Google') can be a useful trick to make the detection slightly more future proof. Requires testing though to not detect some unwanted browsers as Google-made.