# Failing to use document object inside of react component. "document is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've got some browser sniffing code that I'm using inside of a react component

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const SomeComponent = ({props}) => {
  const isIE = document.documentMode;
  return (
    <div>
      Some browser sniffing code here.
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm getting this error on build, though,
"document is not defined"

It also fails when I try it like this

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const isIE = document.documentMode;

const SomeComponent = ({props}) => {
  console.log(isIe)
  return (
    <div>
      Some browser sniffing code here.
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm running from a create-react-library component in a next server.

What's the best way to access the document object inside of react?

I've seen some browser sniffing react code here but it didn't work cause I got the errors on build [Browser Detection in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328382/browser-detection-in-reactjs)

Comment: where is the React.render() function? Can I take a look?

Comment: there isn't a render function in the file because it is a function component (function components don't have render functions in the syntax)

Comment: please take a look on your file app.js or index.js you definitely found this piece of code

ReactDOM.render(
  <App
  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `Next.js`, you should be aware that some of your code will be run in the server-side where `window`, `document` and other browser specific APIs will be not available.

Since `useEffect` hook only runs in the client-side, you can use it together with `useState` to achieve your goal:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const SomeComponent = ({ props }) => {
  const [isIE, setIsIE] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsIE(document.documentMode);
  }, []);
  if (!isIE) return null;
  return <div>Some browser sniffing code here.</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`Next.js` is a SSR framework, your code will run both on server-side and client side. `Window` would be not defined when running on server-side. If you want to get property from `window`, you could try these way.

1. Get the `window` when you need

   ```
   if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      console.log(window.document)
   }
   ```

2. In some specific situation, you need to run your component `only` on client side. In that case, you could using `dynamic`.

   **components/ClientSideComponent**

   ```
   const ClientSideComponent = props => {
       // You could get window directly in this component 
       console.log(window.document)
       return (
         <div>
            run your code only on client side
         </div>
       )
   }
   ```

   **pages/index**

   ```
   import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
   const ClientSideComponent = dynamic(() => import('../components/ClientSideComponent'), {
       ssr: false,
   });

   const HomePage = props => {
       return <ClientSideComponent />
   }
   ```