# How to fix "ReferenceError: Blob is not defined" in NextJs?

Tags: node.js, webpack, next.js, qr-code

Hi I was trying to use `react-qr-reader` in next js but having the problem

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: Blob is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
external%20%22react-qr-reader%22 (1:0) @ Object.react-qr-reader

> 1 | module.exports = require("react-qr-reader");
Call Stack
__webpack_require__
webpack\bootstrap (21:0)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```js
const QrScan = dynamic(() => import('react-qr-reader'), { ssr: false })
```

Answer (score 1):

The [official docs](https://github.com/JodusNodus/react-qr-reader) says **Server side rendering won't work** for `react-qr-reader`. So you need to do is to avoid applying `react-qr-reader` in server-side. You can use the [dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) to solve the problem. You can also reference from the solution 2 of this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822902/failing-to-use-document-object-inside-of-react-component-document-is-not-defin/62826461#62826461) to get some example code.

Answer (score 1):

Great work guys, this works for me

```
import { useState } from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const QrReader = dynamic(() => import("react-qr-reader"), { ssr: false });


export default function ScanPage() {
const [state, setState] = useState("");

return (
<>
<div>{state}</div>
<QrReader delay={100}
onError={(err) => setState(err)}
onScan={(data) => setState(data)}
style={{ width: "95vw"}}
/>
</>
);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue on `voice-recorder-react` library. So after some work-arounds I was be able to solve it.

I just fixed by making the page csr (Client-Side-Rendering)
like this:

```
const HomePage = dynamic(() => import("./home"), { ssr: false });
```

And then I used the library as normal way of importing (in my home page).

```
import { useRecorder } from "voice-recorder-react";
```

So basically some of libraries need to be rendered on client-side.