# React application is not working Internet Explorer how to redirect to error page when the application

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer, runtime-error, load

I have a react application which is working fine in Google chrome but when loaded in Internet explore the application is not loaded and following error pop's up in console

[image]

I just wanted to know is there way when react app is loaded in IE can we redirect to a default page saying application not supported in chrome

please let me know how can i do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Browser Detection in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328382/browser-detection-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-device-detect](https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect) to detect IE and render some message in React.

You can install it using npm or yarn:

```
npm install react-device-detect --save

or

yarn add react-device-detect
```

If you want to detect IE, you can use `isIE` selector:

```
import {isIE} from 'react-device-detect';

render() {
    if (isIE) return <div> IE is not supported. Download Chrome/Opera/Firefox </div>
    return (
        <div>...content</div>
    )
}
```

You can also refer to [this article](https://techstacker.com/detect-internet-explorer-react-display-message/) for more information.

Comment: I am not sure isIE is not wokring when i lanuch the app and the above code should be in app.js right

Comment: @dhanalakshmi Which version of `react` and `react-scripts` are you using? I put the above code in `index.js` and it works well in IE 11. You could try to delete `.cache` folder in `node_modules` and delete IE browser cache then try again. You could refer to [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o2w8u4) about where to put the code.

Comment: thanks it is not working in only IE11 version 11.1339.17763.0 for rest it is working fine please let me know what should i do

Comment: You mean in other IE 11 versions it can work but in 11.1339.17763.0 it can't work? What is the OS version you are using? Is there any error in console? You can try to check if you're using compatibility view in that specific IE 11 version.