# How do I convert image type In React- webp to png or jpg?

Tags: reactjs

A short snippet of code would be really helpful. I have tried using Node and all but I have backend on django, so I just need to convert `.webp` image to other format if the browser is Safari, and I need to to do it using React if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To detect browser using **ReactJS** please check the link below  [Browser Detection in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328382/browser-detection-in-reactjs)

To covert image format using reactjs i don't think this is the best way but it can help you
install the package *react-image-webp*

```
npm install react-image-webp
```

then use

```
import react from 'react'
import Image from 'react-image-webp';

const imageLoader = ()=>{
return (<Image
     src={require('./path/to/image.(png or jpg)')}
     webp={require('./path/to/webp')}
 />)
}
```

or

```
import react from 'react'
import {isWebpSupported} from 'react-image-webp/dist/utils';

 const imageLoader = ()=>{
    return ({isWebpSupported() ? <img src={require('./path/to/img.webp')} /> : <img src={require('./path/to/img.png')} /> }
)
    }
```

Comment: the method u suggested is working but, im searching for a way to convert webp to jpg or png in real time ,maybe it doesn't have to be react ...plain javascript is fine but its a focus on "image conversion" in real time while browser is being rendered