# Jquery code not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have this code which hides certain HTML code when using different browser. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var is_chrome = !!window.chrome && !is_opera;
    var is_explorer= typeof document !== 'undefined' && !!document.documentMode && !isEdge;
    var is_firefox = typeof window.InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    var is_safari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var is_opera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

    if(is_chrome || is_firefox)
    {
      $('#otherbrowser').hide();
    }
    else
    {
      $('#logOut').hide();
    }

 });
</script>
```

It works when i use safari and Google Chrome but when i tried using Internet Explorer it does not hide the `#otherbrowser`. What seems to be the problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Because your logic only hides the element if it is chrome or firefox.

Comment: May be your logic to determine if browser is IE, not working as you expecting. Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie-with-jquery

Comment: Look at the code. Regardless of whether `is_explorer` is correct... it's not even being checked

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the variable `isEdge`, that's the reason it's not working in IE. Just remove the `isEdge` condition or add the definition for that.

Also add the `is_explorer` in your `if` condition. So that it will hide the `#otherbrowser` section in IE.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var is_chrome = !!window.chrome && !is_opera;
    var is_explorer= typeof document !== 'undefined' && !!document.documentMode && !isEdge;
    var isEdge = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge') > 0;
    var is_firefox = typeof window.InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
    var is_safari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var is_opera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

    if(is_chrome || is_firefox || is_explorer)
    {
      alert("condition passed");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("condition failed");
    }

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment bro.I appreciate your help. This is the code I used detect the IE browser and its works fine.  ` if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent) || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1 ) 
    {
        $('#logOut').hide();
    }`

Comment: @RonaldTorres The code that you posted in the question doesn't take any notice of your `is_explorer` variable. The code posted in this answer _does_. What relevance is your comment here?