# How to work around this error script5007 unable to get property 'getDisplayMedia' of undefined or null reference on IE?

Tags: javascript, get-display-media

i'm doing a script to know if my browser supports the screen sharing. My Script works on every browser (Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Edge, Safari) except Internet Explorer and i don't know what is the problem.

Can you give me the answer please

```
var getDisplayMedia;
    // Screen sharing is supported by the browser 
    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia || navigator.getDisplayMedia){
        getDisplayMedia = "O";
    }else {
        getDisplayMedia = "N";
    }
    console.log(getDisplayMedia);
```

On Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Edge, Safari it returns O or N.
but on IE got this error :
script5007 unable to get property 'getDisplayMedia' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that `navigator.mediaDevices` exists before checking one of its properties.

```
var getDisplayMedia;
// Screen sharing is supported by the browser 
if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia || 
    navigator.getDisplayMedia
){
    getDisplayMedia = "O";
}else {
    getDisplayMedia = "N";
}

console.log(getDisplayMedia);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices#Browser_compatibility) section of the MediaDevices documentation, it has no support in IE.

I suggest checking the `navigator.userAgent` for the `indexOf("MSIE")` before checking the `mediaDevices` properties.

Comment: Yes so then it should  put getDisplayMedia to "N". but there is script5007 unable to get property 'getDisplayMedia' of undefined or null reference. So my script doesnt works

Comment: @BeWeria I updated the answer with a potential workaround.

Comment: There is my userAgent on IE : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko". indexof("MSIE") will return false

Comment: @BeWeria For IE 11, you'll need to use a regex to match `/Trident.*rv\:11\./`. I'm sorry it's a bit verbose, but I'm not by my computer to try anything else out. Props to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19999868/8108612) for the matcher

Comment: @BeWeria Yes, always implement the simpler solution!