# HTML doubles up the tooltip in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, tooltip

I am working on tooltips with different browsers. Using font awesome plugin hence it converts `<i>` to `<svg>` for this reason `<title>` tag tooltip is not working on IE. so I have used jquery  `$("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' });` this is working as expected in IE but in chrome its showing twice[image]

If I remove title tooltip is completely not showing up so I thought to remove child attribute attribute in html.

Formatted HTML:

```html
    <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-edit fa-w-18 actionButton" name="enter" id="10_0" aria-label="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" onclick="performActionGrant(10,2018097)" accesskey="E" aria-labelledby="svg-inline--fa-title-Kwz2lgOjl6OC" data-prefix="far" data-icon="edit" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
       <title id="svg-inline--fa-title-Kwz2lgOjl6OC">Edit</title>
       <path fill="currentColor" d="M402.3 "></path>
    </svg>
```

wanted to remove title tag with id which equals `svg` aria-labelledby id. 
I have tried mutiple ways but not able to do with DOM or jquery.

Comment: @dandavis I have tried this css but still its showing twice

Comment: Try detecting if the user is using IE and then run your code if they are: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie

It may not be the best way to achieve this, but since IE has been superseded I wouldn't worry too much IMO

Comment: hmm. i guess i would try removing the title once you have the tooltips upgraded. `$("[title]").map((i,e)=>e.removeAttribute("title"));`

Comment: @dandavis still its not removing the attribute

Comment: @LeeTaylor Its possible with it but its not a good practice I believe

Comment: @Juke. Maybe not best practice, but at least you have a back up plan if nothing else works. Sometimes you have to weigh these things up. Especially since IE won't be about in the near future, or at least not supported...

Comment: @LeeTaylor ya I will put that as backup plan but can we do anything with css and jquery

Comment: @Juke Please amend your question to show the html that "doubles up" the tooltips. This will make it easier for people to attempt to answer.

Comment: @LeeTaylor yes, I did it

Comment: @Juke - As in a runnable demo. Please expand the code snippet to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have used browser to detect and put condition to get in

```
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE");
        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) 
        {  
        $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]' }); 
        } 
    });
```