# Switch off vuex-persist if using IE

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-persist

In my vuex store I use the vuex-persist plugin which works great, in all modern browsers. It doesn't work in IE11 and I would like to be able to switch off the plugin if the user is viewing with IE. Is this possible?

My vuex store is pulled into main.js via...
`import store from '@/store/index.js';`

And my store code is...

Vuex - index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import VuexPersist from 'vuex-persist';

import locales from './modules/locales.js';
import pdf from './modules/pdf-preview.js';
import site from './modules/site.js';
import user from './modules/user.js';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const vuexPersist = new VuexPersist({
  key: 'vuex',
  storage: window.localStorage,
  modules: ['pdf','site','user'],
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  },
  modules: {
    locales,
    pdf,
    site,
    user,
  },
  plugins: [vuexPersist.plugin],
});

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the real problem you are encountering is that `window.localStorage` does not exist or does not allow you to store anything, even though Internet Explorer supported that since IE8. The best way is to simply detect the feature that is not supported (in this case localStorage), and simply not load the plugin:

```js
const plugins = [];

let canStoreAnything = !!window.localStorage;
if (canStoreAnything) {
  try {
    window.localStorage.setItem("__test_localstorage_test__", 1);
    window.localStorage.removeItem("__test_localstorage_test__");
  } catch (e) {
    // Probably Safari in incognito mode
    canStoreAnything = false;
  }
}

if (canStoreAnything) {
  const vuexPersist = new VuexPersist({
    key: "vuex",
    storage: window.localStorage,
    modules: ["any"]
  });

  plugins.push(vuexPersist.plugin);
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    any
  },
  plugins
});
```

[image: Edit Switch off vuex-persist if using IE]

If there is another reason to detect Internet Explorer, simply trust the User Agent. It can be spoofed, but should work fine for your use case. Replace `canStoreAnything` with `isIE` which you can calculate with the following line <sup>[[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie#comment46736832_19999868)]</sup>

```
const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') >= 0 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident') >= 0;
```

Comment: Sumurai8, your answer was superb. I have blended it up further to check for IE, and to check for a true / false toggle set by the user. It works superbly and has helped my understanding of what I can do further. 

Many thanks