# How do I set up an alert in Vue.js when using a different browser?

Tags: vue.js, banner

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-alert type="warning">
      Website displays better in Chrome
    </v-alert>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am new to Vue and I want to notify the user only when using IE that there might be issues with the page. If the user uses Chrome then no alert will appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if user is using IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Add a new props to v-alert component :value="boolean"

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-alert type="warning" :value="isIE">
      Website displays better in Chrome
    </v-alert>
  </div>
</template>
```

Inside computed add a new function to check whether the current browser is IE or not:

```
computed: {
    isIE: function () {
      userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
      return userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1 || userAgent.indexOf("Edge/") > -1;
    }
}
```