# React Axios Error in IE 11, but Not Chrome

Tags: json, reactjs, google-chrome, axios, internet-explorer-11

The following works in Chrome, but gives Network Error in IE 11. Same with using Fetch instead of Axios. 
 What am I missing?

```
async componentDidMount() {
    var auth = "Basic " + btoa(process.env.REACT_APP_CREDENTIAL);
    var state = this;

    Axios.get(
      process.env.REACT_APP_URL,
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: auth,
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        state.setState({ data: response.data.value });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

[image: error image]

Comment: Why not including error message in your post? It might be useful.

Comment: Just added as screenshot of the error, which indicates it's a Permission Denied error.  However, the credentials I'm passing in are correct and this works in Chrome with no errors.  Why and how to fix?

Comment: Try to clear the browser data(cache, cookie and so on) or [reset IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) and check whether it works well. Besides, perhaps this is might be a CORS issue. Try to use F12 developer tools to check the request and response body, and compare them in Chrome and IE browser. Then, perhaps we have to add the CORS manually.

Comment: I'm not seeing the request and response headers in IE 11 or Edge.  Tried adding  Pragma: "no-cache, no-store" and "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store" to the headers, but still nothing.  Also, tried adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to headers as well.  Still no luck.  When drilling down the error, it looks like Axios is passing through the headers in IE and Edge.  If it's a CORS issue, wouldn't it affect Chrome as well?  I've added Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * on the server as well. Still the same Network Error in IE and Edge.

Comment: Try to refer o the following steps: Open Internet Option, select the Security tab, then select the Local intranet and click “sites”, in the popup window, click Advanced button, Add here your domain or localhost, finally click the close button and save change. Then, re-Open IE/Edge and test your code. If still not working, you could also check the IE/Edge browser proxy setting, make sure they are not using a proxy server.

Comment: Just tried all that and confirmed not using any proxy.  Unfortunately, still no luck.

Comment: Try to [detect the IE browser using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie), then using JQuery Ajax to send the request in IE browser, and using Axios method in other browsers.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, any idea how to fix it?