# Is it possible to make a website that only works properly in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: web, internet-explorer, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, intentional-programming

I know this is counterintuitive to the norm and would raise some eyebrows but I'm planning on making an easter egg of sorts for my circle of friends and want the website I'm making to only be available on Internet Explorer 11.

With that in mind, what are some things that I can do so that my website could only render in Internet Explorer aside from ActiveX controls? Are there IE-specific HTML tags or JavaScript functions I can use that don't work on modern day browsers?

I initially thought of just checking the browser's user agent but that's too easy to get around with, however, I would prefer that they don't need to download additional things (Silverlight, etc) and just use the default Internet Explorer included with Windows 10.

Comment: You could find inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/check-if-user-is-using-ie/21712356).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to check browser's user agent, you can check [documentMode Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_documentmode.asp) to detect IE.

`document.documentMode` is only supported by IE, so you can check this property to make functions only works in IE. Please refer to the sample JavaScript code below:

```
if (window.document.documentMode) {
  // Do IE stuff
}
```